# How would I implement the try/except/else structure to my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for my Informatics class assignment it is asking me to use a try/except/else structure to my code. I know im not supposed to post beginner friendly questions on this website but I am in need of help.

Check that the user enters a valid month number and a valid day number. Use a try/except/else structure to ensure numeric data is entered. I already have the if/else structure.

I do not know if the question is asking me to use one of them or all three.

Here is my code and it works perfectly fine:

```
#This program will ask the user to enter a month (in numeric form), a day in a months, and a two-digit year.
#Then, determine if this is a special date(the month times the day equals the year).

#Special Date
print("The date February 10, 2020 is special because when it is written in the following format the month times the day equals the year : 2/10/20.")

#Inputs
userInputMonth = int(input("Please enter a valid month:"))
userInputDay = int(input("Please enter a valid day:"))
userInputYear = int(input("Please enter a valid two-digit-year:"))

print()

if userInputMonth * userInputDay == userInputYear:
    print("The date you provided " + str(userInputMonth) + "/" + str( userInputDay) + "/" + \
        str(userInputYear) + " is the special date.")
else:
    print("The date you provided " + str(userInputMonth) + "/" + str(userInputDay) + "/" + \
          str(userInputYear) + " is not the special date.")
```

I just need to figure out how to implement the `try/except/else` structure to make sure that its a valid month, valid day, valid year.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
try:
    userInputMonth = int(input("Please enter a valid month:"))
except ValueError as error:
    print(str(error))
else:
    print("Input month is ok!")
```

If `userInputMonth` is wrong, the above program will print an error message.

---

**Edit**: You can modify your [**code**](https://pastebin.com/MbWsjD7H) as follows.

```
while True:
    try:
        userInputMonth = int(input("Please enter a valid month:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please provide a numeric input for the month. Try again...")
    else:
        break

while True:
    try:
        userInputDay = int(input("Please enter a valid day:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please provide a numeric input for the day:")
    else:
        break

while True:
    try:
        userInputYear = int(input("Please enter a valid two-digit-year:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please provide a numeric input for the year.")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: pastebin.com/MbWsjD7H Here is what I have now, When I enter an invalid value it just goes to the next line and ignores it. I'm trying to get it to repeat until its correct.

Comment: @GeForce see the edit portion of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Try-except-else` in Python works roughly in this way:

```
try:
    dosomething() # see if something works
except:
    handleproblem() # it didn't work, handle the problem
else:
    domorestuff() # it did work, proceed normally
```

In your case, parsing user input would be something that could fail, like if the user input was `abc` instead of a number.

```
try:
    usermonth = int(input("Please enter a valid month:"))
except ValueError as e:
    print("Please provide a numeric input next time")
else:
    print("Thank you, month is ok")
```

That is not a full solution to your problem, but should get you started.

> Use a try/except/else structure to ensure numeric data is entered.

My interpretation of this requirement of your assignment is that you are supposed to do just what I lined out above, use `try-except-else` to make sure the user did in fact enter numeric data.

To give a litte hint on how the structure of your final program could look like:

1. collect user input into variables (do not parse yet, just store it)
2. **try** to parse stored user input with `int()`
3. if (2) fails with **except**ion, print a scolding message
4. **else** print nice message, do that special date thing, etc